# What is the Pythonic way to do a Boolean Mask on a Pandas dataframe using 'in' operator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This failed:

```
blargh = ['38382', '42132']
dfnew = df[df['FVID'] in blargh]
```

Message:

```
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:792: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison result = getattr(x, name)(y)
```

What is the Pythonic way to get this Boolean mask to work?

Comment: dfnew = df[df['FVID'].isin( blargh)] will give you the desired dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for pandas dataframe.isin()

```
dfnew = df[df['FVID'].isin( blargh)]
```